# How to render js.erb file in a string for Rails 3.2?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Here is the code new.js.erb file for Rails 3.2 app:

```
<% if params[:order][:field_changed] == 'quote_id' && @digi_keys.present? %>
  <% @quote_ids.each_with_index do |v, i| %>
    <% quote = PurchaseOrderx.quote_class.find_by_id(v)%>
    <% if quote %>
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_product_name').val("<%=quote.product_name%>");
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_product_spec').val('<%=quote.product_spec%>');
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_unit_price').val('<%=quote.unit_price%>');
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_unit').val('<%=quote.unit%>');      
    <% else %>
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_product_name').val('');
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_product_spec').val('');
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_unit_price').val('');
      $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_unit').val('');
    <% end %> 
    $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_qty').val('');
    $('#order_order_items_attributes_' + <%=@digi_keys[i]%> + '_item_note').val(''); 
    $('#order_po_total').val('');  
  <% end %>
  $('#order_field_changed').val('');
<% end %>
```

What we are trying to do is to save the code above into a string of `js_erb_code` and render it. Since the js_erb_code is mixing both jquery/javascript and erb code together, we are not sure which render option we should use in `new.js.erb`?

```
<% render inline: js_erb_code %>
```

Or

```
<% render js: js_erb_code %>
```

Or is this kind of coding practice problematic?

Comment: are you asking `how to render a partial from js.erb file` ?

Comment: Your code is hard to read and looks ugly. You should use these if else statements in controller and not in your js file. Just render different files depending on your coditions

Comment: @@mohameddiaa27, yes, it is about how render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah your js.erb should work fine as long as your not mixing in html as well. You can use this to turn it into a string:

```
erb  = ERB.new("js_erb_code")
render erb.result
```

Comment: @@isaacsloan, js_erb_code is the string variable which holds the erb view code . Does js_erb_code need to be quote and unquoted in ERB.new()?

Comment: Here is the code which works:   render inline: ERB.new(@js_erb_code).result(binding)